# Angular2: model for nested JSON

Tags: json, angular, angular2-template

I want to parse a nested json in my code but i am facing difficulties in modelling of json please help me for the following json.

```
{  "label": {
"Application": {
  "_default": {
    "defaultIcon": "",
    "defaultRank": 1,
    "defaultLabel": "Name",
    "defaultColor": "#ffffff",
    "displayName": "Application"
  }
}}
```

Comment: add your code where you are trying to parse

Comment: label[Application]._default[displayName]
m using above code but m getting error that _default is undefined

Comment: Your question is not understandable. What are you trying to "model"? What do you mean by "parse"? You want help doing what? What does this have to do with Angular or Angular templates?

Answer (score 0):

You have to export one interface per level of your JSON if you want a full typing over its content.

```
export interface DefaultApplication {
    defaultIcon: string;
    defaultRank: string;
    defaultLabel: string;
    defaultColor: string;
    displayName: string;    
}

export interface Application {
    _default: DefaultApplication;
}

export interface Label {
    Application: Application;
}
```

EDIT: you should parse the JSON using `JSON.parse` before using it as an object, else it'll be a `string`.

Comment: What makes you think this is an answer to the OP's question? Actually, what do you think the OP's question **is**?

Comment: To me, the question can be reformatted as "how to type my json properly with nested data" .

Answer (score 0):

There is no chance for parsing, because you have 4 *{* character and only 3 *}* characters.
Your JSON should look like that:

```
{
    "label": {
        "Application": {
            "_default": {
                "defaultIcon": "",
                "defaultRank": 1,
                "defaultLabel": "Name",
                "defaultColor": "#ffffff",
                "displayName": "Application"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Next time, you should use some JSON formater/validator f.e [this](https://jsonformatter.org/) instead of writing new question.